# Powershell open email draft with Signature

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, signature

I am trying to make a button open an outlook draft that we can type in the "To:" and click on send.

I got most of it working with the following code:

```
$SUBJECT = ('Ticket: ' + $textticketnumber.text)
CreateLink #Function that gets a weblink and stores it to variable $rtblink.Text
$BODY = $rtblink.Text
$EMAILSIG = Get-Content ($env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm")

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.Subject = "$SUBJECT"
$mail.Body = "`n$BODY`n$EMAILSIG"

$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

The issue is that the body of the email has the raw HTML code not the proper signature. I can change the get-content to *.txt instead of .htm but then there is no formatting in the signature, plus it puts it all on one line.

Is there a way to make the body of the code work with html or is there another way to insert the signature into the email with proper formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code is from one of my scripts:

```
$sMsg = Get-Content template.html 

$sRecipientAddr = "someone@example.com"
$sMsgSubject = "Subject"

$oOutlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
$oMapiNs = $oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$oMailMsg = $oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
$oMailMsg.GetInspector.Activate()
$sSignature = $oMailMsg.HTMLBody
[Void]$oMailMsg.Recipients.Add($sRecipientAddr)  
$oMailMsg.Subject = $sMsgSubject
$oMailMsg.HTMLBody = $sMsg + $sSignature
$oMailMsg.Save()
```

I use it with Outlook 2007 and it works. Outlook is configured to automatically add a signature to new messages. `template.html` is a pre-formatted Outlook message saved as HTML.

The idea is not mine but I honestly can't remember where I found the snippet so my apologies to the author in advance.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for getting my Signature. The only issue is that now I am getting a box from outlook saying "A Program is trying to access e-mail address information" - If I comment out the line: $sSignature = $oMailMsg.HTMLBody Then I don't get the message.

Comment: Scratch that: I went back to my original code and updated $mail.body to $mail.HTMLBody and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, using `.HTMLBody` is the key.